# Macro correctly running in the debugging, but when event is triggered it not running after the first event

Tags: excel, vba, formula, eventhandler, vba7

I have a macro associated with a workbook to trigger some events when data is entered in column B.
Along with this, there are two other modules related to this to for uploading excel when so many data are there and one module to protect and unprotect the sheet. Macro works fine in all scenarios except uploading part, when i am uploading any excel to pull the data, the event is triggered only for the first line and the balance items are just being pasted without triggering the event. I tried the debugging the code by putting a line break and running the code line by line while uploading the excel, at that time its properly doing everything, but when i run it, it is only running for the 1st item.

**Main macro**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        If Not Application.CutCopyMode And IsSelectionNotEmptyOrNumeric(Target) Then        ' Check if cell contains a numeric value or is not empty and the change was made by the user
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then        ' Check if multiple cells are selected
        Dim deleteRows As Range        ' Create a range object to store rows to delete
        Dim lastrow As Long
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
            
                On Error Resume Next
                Protect_Unprotect.UnProtectSheet
                
                
                
                Range("A" & cell.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",ROW()-ROW($A$15)+1,""""),0)"
                Range("H" & cell.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",G" & cell.row & "*F" & cell.row & ",""""),0)"
                Range("D" & cell.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!$C$4:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",PriceList!$A$4:$A$7956,0)),"""")"
                Range("G" & cell.row).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!R4C9:R10000C14,IFERROR(MATCH(RC[-5],PriceList!R4C1:R10000C1,0),MATCH(RC[-4],PriceList!R4C1:R10000C1,0)),MATCH(Customer_Database!R3C3,{""P1"",""P2"",""P3"",""P4"",""P5"",""P0""},0)),"""")"
                Range("F" & cell.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($AA1=2,IF(E" & cell.row & ">INDEX(StockList5104!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",StockList5104!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),INDEX(StockList5104!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",StockList5104!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),E" & cell.row & "),IF(E" & cell.row & ">INDEX(StockList5102!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",StockList5102!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),INDEX(StockList5102!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",StockList5102!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),E" & cell.row & ")),0)"
                Range("I" & cell.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$1=2,INDEX(StockList5104!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",StockList5104!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),INDEX(StockList5102!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",StockList5102!$A$2:$A$7956,0))),0)"
                Range("J" & cell.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!$E$4:$E$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",PriceList!$A$4:$A$7956,0)),0)"
                Range("L" & cell.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",G" & cell.row & "/J" & cell.row & "-1,""""),0)"
                Range("N" & cell.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",M" & cell.row & "/J" & cell.row & "-1,""""),0)"
                Range("O" & cell.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",M" & cell.row & "*F" & cell.row & ",""""),0)"
                Range("K" & cell.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",J" & cell.row & "*F" & cell.row & ",""""),0)"
                
                ' Set horizontal alignment and formatting for the cells
                With Range("A" & cell.row)
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With
                With Range("B" & cell.row & ":D" & cell.row)
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                End With
                
                Dim rng1 As Range
                Set rng1 = Union(Range("E" & cell.row), Range("F" & cell.row), Range("I" & cell.row), Range("H8:H10"))
                
                With rng1
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .NumberFormat = "0"
                End With
                
                Dim rng2 As Range
                Set rng2 = Union(Range("G" & cell.row), Range("H" & cell.row), Range("J" & cell.row), _
                    Range("K" & cell.row), Range("M" & cell.row), Range("O" & cell.row), Range("P" & cell.row), Range("R" & cell.row), _
                    Range("H11"), Range("M6"), Range("M8"), Range("M10"))
                
                With rng2
                    .NumberFormat = "0.00_-;[Red]-0.00_-;""-""??_-;@"
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                End With
                
                Dim rng3 As Range
                Set rng3 = Union(Range("N" & cell.row), Range("L" & cell.row), Range("Q" & cell.row), Range("M7"), _
                    Range("M9"), Range("M11"))
                
                With rng3
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
                End With
                
                ' Copy border, border color and orientation from row above
                With Range("A" & cell.row & ":S" & cell.row)
                    .Borders.LineStyle = .Offset(-1, 0).Borders.LineStyle
                    .Borders.Color = .Offset(-1, 0).Borders.Color
                    .Orientation = .Offset(-1, 0).Orientation
                    .HorizontalAlignment = .Offset(-1, 0).HorizontalAlignment
                End With
            Else
                ' Add row to deleteRows range
                If deleteRows Is Nothing Then
                    Set deleteRows = Rows(cell.row)
                Else
                    Set deleteRows = Union(deleteRows, Rows(cell.row))
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
        
                On Error Resume Next
        Protect_Unprotect.ProtectSheet
        
        'Formatting of the Header cells
        With Range("H8:H10")
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .NumberFormat = "0"
        End With
        
        With Range("H11")
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .NumberFormat = "0.00_-;[Red]-0.00_-;""-""??_-;@"
        End With
        
              

        
        'Calculations for the header cells
        lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
        Range("H6").Formula = "=TODAY()"
        Range("H9").Formula = "=IFERROR(SUM(E15:E" & lastrow & "),"""")"
        Range("H8").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B15:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row))
        Range("H10").Formula = "=IFERROR(SUM(F15:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row & "),"""")"
        Range("H11").Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(H15:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
        Range("M6").Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(K15:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
        Range("M7").Formula = "=IFERROR(H11/M6-1,"""")"
        Range("M8").Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(O15:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
        Range("M9").Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(M8/M6-1,2),"""")"
        Range("M10").Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(R15:R" & Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
        Range("M11").Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(M10/M6-1,2),"""")"
        
        ' Delete entire rows in deleteRows range
        If Not deleteRows Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Protect_Unprotect.UnProtectSheet
        
            Application.EnableEvents = False        ' Disable events to avoid triggering the event again
            deleteRows.Delete
            Application.EnableEvents = True        ' Enable events again
        End If

        
        
        
    Else
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
                        On Error Resume Next
                Protect_Unprotect.UnProtectSheet
                
                Range("A" & Target.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",ROW()-ROW($A$15)+1,""""),0)"
                Range("H" & Target.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",G" & Target.row & "*F" & Target.row & ",""""),0)"
                Range("D" & Target.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!$C$4:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",PriceList!$A$4:$A$7956,0)),"""")"
                Range("G" & Target.row).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!R4C9:R10000C14,IFERROR(MATCH(RC[-5],PriceList!R4C1:R10000C1,0),MATCH(RC[-4],PriceList!R4C1:R10000C1,0)),MATCH(Customer_Database!R3C3,{""P1"",""P2"",""P3"",""P4"",""P5"",""P0""},0)),"""")"
                Range("F" & Target.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($AA1=2,IF(E" & Target.row & ">INDEX(StockList5104!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",StockList5104!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),INDEX(StockList5104!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",StockList5104!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),E" & Target.row & "),IF(E" & Target.row & ">INDEX(StockList5102!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",StockList5102!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),INDEX(StockList5102!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",StockList5102!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),E" & Target.row & ")),0)"
                Range("I" & Target.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$1=2,INDEX(StockList5104!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",StockList5104!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),INDEX(StockList5102!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",StockList5102!$A$2:$A$7956,0))),0)"
                Range("J" & Target.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!$E$4:$E$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",PriceList!$A$4:$A$7956,0)),0)"
                Range("L" & Target.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",G" & Target.row & "/J" & Target.row & "-1,""""),0)"
                Range("N" & Target.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",M" & Target.row & "/J" & Target.row & "-1,""""),0)"
                Range("O" & Target.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",M" & Target.row & "*F" & Target.row & ",""""),0)"
                Range("K" & Target.row).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",J" & Target.row & "*F" & Target.row & ",""""),0)"
            
            ' Set horizontal alignment
            With Range("A" & Target.row)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With Range("B" & Target.row & ":D" & Target.row)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            End With
            
            Dim rnge1 As Range
            Set rnge1 = Union(Range("E" & Target.row), Range("F" & Target.row), Range("I" & Target.row))
            
            With rnge1
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .NumberFormat = "0"
            End With
            
            Dim rnge2 As Range
            Set rnge2 = Union(Range("G" & Target.row), Range("H" & Target.row), Range("J" & Target.row), _
                Range("K" & Target.row), Range("M" & Target.row), Range("O" & Target.row), Range("P" & Target.row))
            
            With rnge2
                .NumberFormat = "0.00_-;[Red]-0.00_-;""-""??_-;@"
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            End With
            
            Dim rnge3 As Range
            Set rnge3 = Union(Range("N" & Target.row), Range("L" & Target.row), Range("Q" & Target.row))
            
            With rnge3
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
            End With
            
            ' Copy border, border color and orientation from row above
            With Range("A" & Target.row & ":S" & Target.row)
                .Borders.LineStyle = .Offset(-1, 0).Borders.LineStyle
                .Borders.Color = .Offset(-1, 0).Borders.Color
                .Orientation = .Offset(-1, 0).Orientation
                .HorizontalAlignment = .Offset(-1, 0).HorizontalAlignment
            End With
            
                    On Error Resume Next
        Protect_Unprotect.ProtectSheet
            
            lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
        Range("H6").Formula = "=TODAY()"
        Range("H9").Formula = "=IFERROR(SUM(E15:E" & lastrow & "),"""")"
        Range("H8").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B15:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row))
        Range("H10").Formula = "=IFERROR(SUM(F15:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row & "),"""")"
        Range("H11").Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(H15:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
        Range("M6").Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(K15:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
        Range("M7").Formula = "=IFERROR(H11/M6-1,"""")"
        Range("M8").Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(O15:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
        Range("M9").Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(M8/M6-1,2),"""")"
        Range("M10").Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(R15:R" & Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
        Range("M11").Formula = "=IFERROR(ROUND(M10/M6-1,2),"""")"
            
        
        Else
            
            ' Delete entire row
            On Error Resume Next
            Protect_Unprotect.UnProtectSheet
            
            Application.EnableEvents = False        ' Disable events to avoid triggering the event again
            Rows(Target.row).Delete
            Application.EnableEvents = True        ' Enable events again

        End If

        
        
    End If
    
End If

End If



End Sub

Private Function IsSelectionNotEmptyOrNumeric(selection As Range) As Boolean
    IsSelectionNotEmptyOrNumeric = False
    For Each cell In selection.Cells
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Or cell.Value <> "" Then
            IsSelectionNotEmptyOrNumeric = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
End Function
```

This is the second: **Macro for excel uploading**

```
Option Explicit

    Private Sub Upload_Excel()
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Protect_Unprotect.UnProtectSheet
    
        
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        
        Dim wb          As Workbook
        Dim ws          As Worksheet
        Dim rngA        As Range, rngB As Range
        Dim i           As Long, n As Long
        
        Application.Visible = False
    
        
        'Open the dialog box to select a file
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(Application.GetOpenFilename(), False, True)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        
        'Set the worksheet to import data from
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
        
        'Count the number of rows to import
        n = ws.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
        
        
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Visible = True
        'Show the progress bar userform
        UserForm1.Show vbModeless
        
        'Copy the data from column A and B of the selected worksheet
        Set rngA = ws.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        Set rngB = ws.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        
    
        
        'Paste the data to Quote_Master worksheet starting from cell A15 and E15
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_Master")
            For i = 1 To n
                .Range("B15").Offset(i - 1).Value = rngA.Cells(i).Value
                .Range("E15").Offset(i - 1).Value = rngB.Cells(i).Value
                'Update the progress bar
                UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value = i / n * 100
                DoEvents
            Next i
        End With
        
        'Close the workbook without saving changes
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
        On Error Resume Next
        
        'Hide the progress bar userform
        UserForm1.Hide
        Unload UserForm1
        
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        Protect_Unprotect.ProtectSheet
        
        Exit Sub
        
        
        
        
    ErrorHandler:
        Application.Visible = True
        MsgBox "The Upload was cancelled."        'Display message if the user cancels or closes the dialog box
        
    End Sub
```

**Macro for protect & unprotect the sheet**

```
Sub ProtectSheet()
    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim rnge        As Range
    Dim rnge2       As Range
    
    Set wb = Workbooks("Quote Master.xlsm")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Quote_Master")
    
    Set rnge2 = ws.Range("B15:B1000", "E15:E1000")
    
    Set rnge = Union(ws.Range("A15:A1000"), ws.Range("C15:D1000"), ws.Range("F15:G1000"))
    
    With rnge2
    On Error Resume Next
       .Locked = False
      .FormulaHidden = False
    End With
    
    With rnge
        
        
        .Locked = True
        .FormulaHidden = True
    End With
    

    
    ws.Protect "123", True, True
    
End Sub

Sub UnProtectSheet()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "123"
End Sub
```

Comment: You code is currently dependent on an 'Implicit' activesheet reference.   This means the active sheet when running and debugging are likely to be different.  You should start by qualifying all your Worksheet accesses.  Then install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and pay attention to the Code Inspection.

Comment: @freeflow re _You code is currently dependent on an 'Implicit' activesheet reference._. No, it's not.  This code will be in a sheet behind module.   In that location an unqualified range  reference refers to that sheet, not ActiveSheet

Comment: @sanjay using `On Error Resume Next` without a following `On Error Goto 0` disables all error handling from that point on.  You may be ignoring errors You don't mean to

Comment: @chrisneilsen: Thanks for the tip, i am doing that and trying to crack my errors.